# Geolocation on nodejs server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, geolocation, chromium

I'm running a webpage on a local node.js server using the Chromium browser on my Raspberry Pi 3b+. I'm trying to get the webpage to find my location using a javascript code like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    (position)=>console.log(position),
    (error)=>console.warn(error),
    {
       timeout:2500,
       enableHighAccuracy:true
    }
);
```

This works completely fine on my laptop, but on the raspberry pi it only results in this error message:

```
network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' no response received
```

I've tried:

- to expand the timeout option.
- multiple wireless networks.
- checking google maps if i actually can find my location on the raspberry, which it does...

So now im wondering if it is a bug with chromium or the google api, or if the raspberry somehow disables geolocation. Does anyone know if there is a workaround or another solution to get my location that I can use?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss the ":" after "https"?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately no... The typo was only from when I wrote the question :/

Comment: Did you grant the permission for your app when chromium asked if it can use your location?

Comment: Yes. When the popup asks for permission i click yes, and immediately after that the error message appears

Comment: Are you using your own Chromium fork? The Geolocation API will require billing to be enabled in your Google cloud account associated with the API keys used in your Chromium

Comment: @Asesh Im not using my own chromium fork. Im using the version i got using npm install --save chromium. 
Im not sure if there is a way to check if the API keys is active in that one or if i can add custom keys?

Comment: Then you can define these env. variables: `GOOGLE_API_KEY=your_api_key
GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID=your_client_id
GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET=your_client_secret` with your API keys. More info can be found here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys Also you must enable billing for your Google cloud account to enable Geolocation, otherwise it won't work